# html select with custom user defined option

Tags: jquery, select, input

i would like to create an html select element that a user may use to select his favorite something OR in case that his favorite is not in the list there is also a select option "define your own" and if you click it the select turns into a text input.

Mayhaps there is a jquery plugin/solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

Create your select list in HTML. Create your input in HTML. Hide the input with CSS `display:none`. Then use jQuery (don't forget to include jquery library at beggining of page) `.change()` function to check if your item gets selected. When it is selected just do : `$("#selectlist").hide(); $("#inputfield").show();`

Comment: Dear @barakadam can you explain it with an example.